# Customize list view in modern SharePoint online site without scripting

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

we are not allowed to use the custom scripts in our SharePoint. every time I add CSS it strips it out and doesn't work.

[image]

how do you hide it using JSON.?

Comment: You've formatted the view using view formatting?

Comment: Are you using "Tile" view in SharePoint? You need to use JSON formatting in SharePoint in order to remove the default content in list view.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no JSON to hide it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.